# Django model without primary and unique field

Tags: python, django

I have an DB table:

```
  url_id( INT(11) )  |   monitor_id( (INT(11) )
 --------------------+--------------------------
        1            |         1
        1            |         2
        1            |         3
        2            |         2
```

And so on. Neither `url_id` nor `monitor_id` field aren't unique, more than that, they are Foreign Keys for other tables (table `urls` and table `monitors`). So I cant change DB structure. In my Django models file I created a model class for this table:

```
class MonitorForUrl(models.Model):
    url = models.ForeignKey(Url, primary_key=True)
    monitor = models.ForeignKey(Monitor)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'monitors_for_url'
```

I set `primary_key` parameter for true, becouse Django creates default `*model_name*_id` field for primary key, if I don't set my own primary key field. There is no such field in DB so I set `primary_key` for true. In this way I cant create some rows with similar `url_id` value, becouse it's primary key. Can I tell Django not to create default primary key field without setting `primary_key` option, or maybe you can advice me some other ways to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a model for this. Instead, add a [many-to-many relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) in either the Url and Monitor model.

Django will then maintain this intermediate table for you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to make composite primary key, but django doesn't support it:
https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys

What you could do is to let it create id field, but also add unique constraint like this:

```
class MonitorForUrl(models.Model):
    url = models.ForeignKey(Url, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    monitor = models.ForeignKey(Monitor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'monitors_for_url'
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['url', 'monitor']
                name='unique_url_monitor'
            )
        ]
```

Neither field will be unique, but combination of the fields will.